# Problems changing the color of the shape drawn by PolyDraw from winGDI

Tags: winapi, rust, gdi

I try to do some basic drawing like so:

```rust
pub fn draw_rect(dc: *mut HDC__, rect: RECT, (r, g, b): (u8, u8, u8)) {
    let original = unsafe { SelectObject(dc, DC_PEN as HGDIOBJ) };
    let prev_color = unsafe {SetDCPenColor(dc, RGB(r,g,b))};
    // some vector bs here
    unsafe {
        PolyDraw(dc, pts.as_ptr(),  pt_instructions.as_ptr(),  num_pts);
        SetDCPenColor(dc, prev_color);
        DeleteObject(SelectObject(dc, original));
    }
}
```

and drawing it does - just always black. I dont have a monochrome dc - thats for sure, cuz GDITransparentBlt works ok. And i think im right on the order of things:

```
1. select pen as current object, saving the old one
2. change pen color, store the old one,
3. do the drawing,
4. reasign the old color,
5. load the old object
```

Answer (score 3):

So - just as I posted it I realized that what I'm doing in the first line of the function is nonsense, as DC_PEN is just a u32 (DWORD) constant, which is by no means a GDIOBJECT. To get one from DC_PEN, i had to change it to

```rust
pub fn draw_rect(dc: *mut HDC__, rect: RECT, (r, g, b): (u8, u8, u8)) {
    let original = unsafe { SelectObject(dc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN as i32)) };
    let prev_color = unsafe {SetDCPenColor(dc, RGB(r,g,b))};
    ...
```

and now it works.